# can i loop a select in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this query :

```
select count(*)
from Table o
where 
(o.time between timevariable1 and addtime(timevariable1,timeincrement)
and o.Date="whatever date";
```

i'm trying to loop this query 10 times, incrementing the timevariable1 whit the timeincrement.

i want to retrive the count(*) of the rows that have a time between a range.
but i have 10 different ranges of times.

from  00:00  to  00:10       10 rows

from  00:10  to  00:20       4 rows

....and so on

the first value of timevariable1 and the value of time increment is calculeted in my code.

can i do it whit a stored procedure in mysql ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you are  trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one query like this

```
select sum(time between timevariable1 and addtime(timevariable1,timeincrement)) as t1count,
       sum(time between timevariable2 and addtime(timevariable2,timeincrement)) as t2count
from Table
where Date='whatever date'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table to create a list of values and then use `left join`.  Something like this:

```
select tv.val1, count(*)
from (select val1 as timevariable union all
      select val2 . . . 
     ) tv left join
     Table o
     on  o.time between tv.timevariable and addtime(tv.timevariable, timeincrement) and
         o.Date = 'whatever date;
```